# What do viruses do?

Tags: agar.io

There are those big green spiked things that my friends call viruses. I don't know what they do and I want to know. Do the viruses do something to the device you are playing on? Are they good or bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://agario.wikia.com/wiki/Virus):

> The Virus is a special kind of entity existing in all agar.io modes. They appear as cell-like entities which are surrounded in spikes. When a cell of 133 mass or greater consumes a virus, they will split into many pieces, making them easy targets for other cells, but gain 100 mass. Players' cells not large enough to consume a virus will pass through it harmlessly, making it a safe haven for small cells. The virus can also hide a small cell inside of it, so small cells can use viruses to hide from large cells or plot a sneak attack, though, when a player's cell is larger than another player's cell and very near to 133 mass, he will not hide behind it, but rather be seen in front of it.
>   Once a player has 16 independent cells, running into a virus with a cell of over 132 mass will result in the virus being consumed without additional splitting, only gaining 100 mass.
>
> A new virus can be created by a cell by ejecting 7 blobs at a maximum by using the W function. When the virus is given the seventh blob, it will eject another virus in the direction the player is moving. This mechanic is often used to attack larger cells who would otherwise be impossible to consume for the player. Keep in mind that when a cell is in range to give mass to a virus, it is also in range for the ejected virus. Ejecting viruses at other cells has considerable risk of counterattack. Viruses that are closer to ejection appear swollen and have more spikes.

Comment: While I'm not against using wikis for the answer, I downvoted this for answering with a copy-paste. That said, I had not played around with the virus much, in agar, and decided to play around. **I found some of the stuff the wiki says to be inaccurate or obsolete.** I believe this may mostly concern "experimental mode", which I expect would change quite a bit. I have posted an answer based off playing the game, and tested out a majority of it, myself.

Comment: Nothing in this answer is inaccurate or obsolete relating to FFA mode as of today - with the possible exception that the 133 mass threshold to consume a virus may only apply to viruses that have not been "fed" at all.

Answer (score 8):

In context of Agario, viruses are a unique cell, not to be confused with a computer virus. They appear as cells with a dark, spiked circumference.

### The Green Virus

[image: The Green Virus]

**The green virus is often used as hideout for smaller players, and an obstacle for larger players.**

Smaller players will automatically hide underneath the virus. You can tell if a player is under a virus quite easily; When there is a player under the virus, the outside will exhibit "rips", as shown in the above picture.

If the player is approximately the same size as the virus, they will glide over the top. However, if the player is big enough to consume the virus, they will do so. While consuming a virus will raise the players mass, it will also split the player into smaller pieces, making them far more vulnerable.

**If a player can consume a virus, but have already hit the maximum of 16 splits, they will not split.** They will still consume the virus, and gain the appropriate mass.

Green viruses can be "fed", by ejecting mass into them. When they get big enough ([the Wiki reports a maximum of 7 feeds](http://agario.wikia.com/wiki/Virus)), they will split into two separate viruses.

#### Wiki Inaccuracy

That said, this agar changes regularly. The information on the wiki is often outdated or inaccurate. At the time of writing this, there are no dark viruses in experimental mode. I personally checked this, accessing the various servers in spectator mode. Viruses react to comparative mass, not an exact number (you have to be bigger to consume, not exactly 133 mass). Also, I can confirm that you can feed green viruses in experimental mode.

Comment: ... How about *red* viruses? (Okay, maroon; redy-brown)

Comment: I often see it called the 'dark virus'. My answer comes from checking the wikis, and actually testing out the information, in game. At the time of writing this answer, the dark virus was not active in the game. They were referenced as being exclusive to experimental mode. my guess is that they were cut. If I see them pop up in my play, I might come back and update my answer.

Comment: "You can tell if a player is under a virus quite easily" This is absolutely untrue. It is possible to tell when a player _of a certain size_ (relative to the virus) is hiding in the virus. It is quite easy for a smaller player to hide inside a virus undetectably.

Answer (score 0):

A brown or dark virus is actually a mother cell. A mother cell spews 1 or 2 mass pellets for people to eat. When you're smaller than the "mother cells " you will die and gave the mother cell mass. When you eat the mother cell it works like viruses but give you 200 mass instead of 100. It works like viruses when you have the Maximus piece, 16, you can just eat them without exploding.