# When can an Agar virus eat a Thorn Blob?

Tags: agar.io

I see sometimes that some really huge viruses can eat the thorn blobs. However, some more have gotten popped when tried to do it.

So, what should be the general size and cases in which a virus can be able to eat a thorn blob?

Comment: I have also noticed some medium sized player blobs (about the size as the thorn blob) pass through the thorn blob without popping. This is on agar.io.

Comment: @RikerW Yeah, small/medium sized blogs almost always pass through them. But, some large ones end up eating them whole :)

Comment: Oh, cool? Never tried that.

Comment: related question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229542/what-do-viruses-do

Comment: Agar has probably changed quite a bit since I played, but I still seldom play, and have never seen a virus split a player without being consumed. Previously, the only way to not split was to already be at a certain maximum of splits, i.e. already being split into so many pieces that it won't split you apart any more.

Comment: Also, Ive never seen the player refered to as a virus. I do commonly see the 'thorn blobs' referred to as a virus.